# passport.js passport-twitter.js node.js odd 500 errors

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth, passport.js, passport-twitter

I have been trying to get passport.js / passport-twitter working with my project using Jared Hanson's nice [tutoral](http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/66118192565/getting-started-with-passport)  and it's attendant [gist](https://gist.github.com/jaredhanson/3989193).

Needless to say, the gist works just fine. I simply add my keys, alter my callback url and it just works.

I have set the url "whackypants.dev" in my /etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1. This works fine with the gist example.

My problem is, I'm getting some rather weird and inconsistent errors when attempting to integrate passport, passport-twitter and connect-ensure-login with my existing app.

When I click the "sign in with twitter" on /login, I am, as expected, taken to twitter and given a nice oauth token:

```
http://whackypants.dev:8080/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=I9sGWDKRyWCJcpM3nLx3Tt3sTGRhTVYUKj03ZYIcYk&oauth_verifier=qiRQt1DGpxH2QF4zHrbKbVGj0qXTy5y2S2Sh8Ts10x7
```

However, express throws a 500:

```
Express
500 failed to fetch user profile (status: 410 data: {"errors": [{"message":
"The Twitter REST API v1 will soon stop functioning. Please migrate to API v1.1.  
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]})
at /Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/passport-twitter/lib/passport-  
twitter/strategy.js:107:30
at passBackControl (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/passport- 
twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:374:13)
at IncomingMessage. (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/passport-  
twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:386:9)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:910:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I would have expected the gist example to throw the same error.

Even weirder: When I just use localhost:8080/login I get:

```
http://brandery-project.dev:8080/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=0PjNkHRMaKjG7KwlXXzUPpiFk6urANvClWK8inB58&oauth_verifier=7A2GtRUf1Q3B2HlxBVGQm4BAQIIEvdYIbBB2GZHBZ
```

and an altogether different 500 error:

```
Express
500 Error: failed to find request token in session
at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/passport-   
twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth.js:124:54)
at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/passport-  
twitter/lib/passport-twitter/strategy.js:82:40)
at attempt   
(/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/
authenticate.js:243:16)
at Passport.authenticate     
(/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/
authenticate.js:244:7)
at callbacks (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
at param (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
at pass (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch 
(/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (/Users/doug/whackypants/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/
proto.js:190:15)
```

When I again hit localhost:8080/login and refresh, I can see the oauth token in my cookies:

```
{
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true
    },
    passport: {},
    'oauth:twitter': {
        oauth_token: '0PjNkHRMaKjG7KwlXXzUPpiFk6urANvClWK8inB58',
        oauth_token_secret: 'aW4zeuCrdrmPxpBzu7U2xDHu1DNQhEFHoGyufhY5mU'
    }
}
```

I have been trying to understand the different problems. At first I thought it might have to do with the order in which I have the middleware placed in the chain, but it looks "right".

Actual code follows. Clues appreciated.

**app.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    exphbs  = require('express3-handlebars'),
    package = require('./package.json');

var app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8080,
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

console.log('\ninitializing ' + package.name + ' (' + env + ')');

// expose application properties to views
app.locals({
    app: {
        name: package.name,
        version: package.version,
        env: env
    }
});

// set Handlebars as the view engine
console.log('... initializing handlebars view engine');
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    helpers: require('./helpers')
});
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// allow the application to sit behind a proxy
app.enable('trust proxy');

// initialize middleware
console.log('... initializing middleware');
app.use(express.favicon('public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showTrace: true}));

// initialize application routes
console.log('... initializing routes');
require('./routes').init(app);

// start server
app.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ' + port);
```

**routes/login.js**

```
    var passport = require('passport')
    , TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy
    , ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;

exports.init = function(app) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
        done(null, obj);
    });

    var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "consumerkey";
    var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "consumersecret";
    var TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "http://develop.dev:8080/auth/twitter/callback";

    passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
        consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
        consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        callback_url: TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL
        }, function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
            var user = profile;
            return done(null, user);
        })
    );

    app.get('/account', ensureLoggedIn('/login'),
        function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session);
        res.send('Hello ' + req.user.username);
        });

    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session);
        res.send('<html><body><a href="/auth/twitter">Sign in with Twitter</a></body></html>');
        });

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
        });

    app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

    app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));
}
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var login = require('./login');
exports.init = function (app) {
     //extraneous api stuff removed
     login.init(app);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter API v1.0 is [deprecated](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired) from today.

You need to update `passport-twitter` to v0.1.5 (`npm install passport-twitter`).

Comment: Well, that was quite a long question for such a short (and absolutely correct) answer. Thanks maxdec.